# How to create azure policies against storage account logging

Tags: azure-storage, azure-policy

I would like to create a deployIfNotExists policy against storage account logs (enable them if they are not, and if possible, add a trigger to them).  If this is not possible, I would at least like an audit policy on them. But this functionality does not appear to exist at this time. Is this possible or does this process have to be "manual"?

Answer (score 0):

There has to be an alias for this to be possible. I didn't find one from the storage resource, but in log profiles I found this: "Microsoft.Insights/logProfiles/storageAccountId". However I am not sure if that is the same thing that you are looking for. There is also this built in that can help: https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/built-in-policies/policyDefinitions/Monitoring/ActivityLog_StorageAccountBYOK_Audit.json